# Java 9 service provider and Groovy Extension Modules

Tags: java, groovy, vert.x, java-9, java-module

In a java 9 project, I'd like to require `vertx.web`, which is the automatic name given for module `io.vertx:vertx-web:3.4.2`.  Only, at runtime, I get the following error.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.vertx/vertx-web/3.4.2/eee42405acff13d37eb2a62256189d419f91aa4d/vertx-web-3.4.2.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class moduleFactory = io.vertx.groovy.ext.web.VertxPropertiesModuleFactory not in module
```

It seems that vertx-web makes use of [Groovy Extension Modules](http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html).  This is why file `META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` exists.  Java9 reads this file wrongfully for [Service Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Is there any way to ignore this service file as it is in a dependency and I cannot change it ?

Comment: META-INF/services is specified in the JAR file spec to be used for service provider configuration files. The configuration files for the Groovy Extension Modules appear to be properties files, they really need to find a different place to put those.

Comment: So I guess that Groovy spec has to change in order to avoid such conflict.  Even if this were done, existing dependencies would still be unusable with Java9

Comment: this will be fixed in Vert.x 3.5.0, writing a Java 9 modular application with Vert.x anonymous modules will be possible https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/3.5.0-staging/java9-examples